# Xamarin Forms Resize Image inside Listview

Tags: xamarin, android-imageview, android-image, xamarin.forms

How can I set the size of the image inside of a list view. Currently I have several lists that have icons but I don't see any options for changing the aspect ratio or size of the image so it just gets blown up to the height of the list item.

all the images are from the Drawable folder

```
        var cell = new DataTemplate(typeof(MenuTextCell));
        cell.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "Title");
        cell.SetBinding(ImageCell.ImageSourceProperty, "IconSource");
        cell.SetValue(BackgroundColorProperty, Color.Transparent);
        cell.SetValue(TextCell.TextColorProperty, Color.FromHex("262626"));
```

I am using a custom renderer

```
public class MenuTextCellRenderer : ImageCellRenderer
    {
        protected override View GetCellCore (Cell item, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, Context context)
        {
            var cell = (LinearLayout)base.GetCellCore (item, convertView, parent, context);
            cell.SetPadding(20, 10, 0, 10);
            cell.DividerPadding = 50;

            var div = new ShapeDrawable();
            div.SetIntrinsicHeight(1);
            div.Paint.Set(new Paint { Color = Color.FromHex("b7b7b7").ToAndroid() });

            if (parent is ListView)
            {
                ((ListView)parent).Divider = div;
                ((ListView)parent).DividerHeight = 1;
            }

            var icon = (ImageView)cell.GetChildAt(0);

            var label = (TextView)((LinearLayout)cell.GetChildAt(1)).GetChildAt(0);
            label.SetTextColor(Color.FromHex("262626").ToAndroid());
            label.TextSize = Font.SystemFontOfSize(NamedSize.Large).ToScaledPixel();
            label.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
            label.Text = label.Text.ToUpper();

            var secondaryLabel = (TextView)((LinearLayout)cell.GetChildAt(1)).GetChildAt(1);
            secondaryLabel.SetTextColor(Color.FromHex("262626").ToAndroid());
            secondaryLabel.TextSize = Font.SystemFontOfSize(NamedSize.Large).ToScaledPixel();
            label.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;


            return cell;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are now dealing with an **Android** `ImageView`.

You have your reference via `var icon = (ImageView)cell.GetChildAt(0)`.

You can now customize it via methods such as `.setScaleType()` for aspect ratio related, and use `.layout()` to change the position / size.

Comment: so .Layout() seems like it deals with position fine but I don't see anything related to size.

Comment: @BillPull - its the third and fourth parameters to adjust width and height.

Comment: Can this be declared within XAML?

Comment: @ScottNimrod This is platform-specific for `Android`.  I answered your other question with regard to image size from XAML with your ListView that you are most likely interested in more? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647976/how-do-i-set-the-size-of-an-image-within-a-listview/35663733#35663733)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this on your ListView.ItemTemplate, instead of using the imagecell. You can also write your custom cell.

```
<DataTemplate>
<ViewCell>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10"> 
        <Image Aspect="AspectFill" HeightRequest ="20" WidthRequest="20" Source="{Binding IconSource}" /> 
        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" YAlign="Center" Font="Medium" />
    </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```