# How do I set the size of an image within a ListView?

Tags: xamarin.forms

How do I set the size of an image within a ListView?

The targeted device is Windows Phone 10 (i.e. Windows Universal Platform).

I've discovered the following [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance/#ImageCell):

> Note that when targeting Windows Phone 8.1, ImageCell will not scale
>   images by default. Also, note that Windows Phone 8.1 is the only
>   platform on which detail text is presented in the same color and font
>   as primary text by default. Windows Phone 8.0 renders ImageCell as
>   seen below:

**I've tried:**

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Photos}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPhoto, Mode=TwoWay}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding ImageSource}" Text="{Binding Description}" TextColor="Silver" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The above image shows a full-blown image without confining the size of the image to fit as a listview item.

**I've also tried:**

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Photos}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPhoto, Mode=TwoWay}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Aspect="AspectFit" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The above code doesn't show any image. It just shows a white background.

Comment: have you tried setting the widthrequest and horizontaloptions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Few things:-

`ImageCell` has no ability to specify the image width / height (v2.0.x).

Your second example is more on track, however, you need to wrap it in a `ViewCell` as you are dealing with a `ListView` like so:-

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Photos}" HasUnevenRows="True">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>            
      <ViewCell>
        <Image Source="{Binding MyImage}" Aspect="AspectFit" WidthRequest="{Binding MyWidth}" HeightRequest="{Binding MyHeight}" />
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Also, note that the default for a `ListView` is set to have **equal** row heights.

Therefore if you have different image sizes, chances are this may not produce the output you want.

To get around this, specify `HasUnevenRows='True'`.

If you further do `BindableProperties` for what you want the `ImageWidth` and `ImageHeight` in your `ViewModel`, and specify them as in the example above using `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest` for `Image` you will get something like this for the output when specifying different values:-

[image]

Comment: Thanks Pete. This works when I use StackLayouts. But this doesn't work when I replace stacklayouts with a grid. Is this a known bug?

Comment: @ScottNimrod It would be best to create a new question, with a code example as its unclear how your structuring things and would help to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding salt to a cooked meal, You can also do it dynamically:

```
 <Slider x:Name="slider" Maximum="600"  Minimum="30"  />

    <ListView RowHeight="55" x:Name="lv_prayers_categories_page" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding SimpleList}"  
              HasUnevenRows="true" 
              BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
              SeparatorVisibility="None">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee" HeightRequest="50"   >
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding Image}" HeightRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference slider}, Path=Value}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                TextColor="#f35e20" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding ID}"
                                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                TextColor="#503026" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

View Modal:

```
private ObservableCollection<SimpleImage> _impleList;
public ObservableCollection<SimpleImage> SimpleList
{
    get => _impleList;
    set => SetProperty(ref _impleList, value);
}

    SimpleList = new ObservableCollection<SimpleImage>()
    {
        new SimpleImage(){
            ID = 0,
            Name = "Female",
            Image = "https://griffonagedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/profile-modern-2e.jpg"

        },
        new SimpleImage(){
            ID = 1,
            Name = "Male",
            Image = "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/profile-view-of-confident-sportsman-picture-id488758510?k=6&m=488758510&s=612x612&w=0&h=yIwLu2wdd2vo317STdyNlKYIVIEJEFfDKfkY8pBIfaA="

        },
        new SimpleImage(){
            ID = 2,
            Name = "Android",
            Image = "https://www.cnn.co.jp/storage/2015/11/06/17626d508c2c2a8c8c322d353631a431/zuckerberg-getty.jpg"

        },
    };
```

Modal:

```
public class SimpleImage : BindableBase
{
    private int _id;
    public int ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _id, value); }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _name, value); }
    }

    private ImageSource _image;
    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get { return _image; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _image, value); }
    }

}
```